# How to distinguish the features in Openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

Recently, I am developing a mapping tool and choose openlayers3 as the front end map APi. 
In my map layer, it has geometries and images, i would like to add a function, when i click on different kind of feature, it will do different actions.

In the code, i need to recognize it comes from image or geometry. I am appreciate  any help from you guys.

Comment: A downvote could have an explanation so the OP won't be left in the dark.

Comment: Let us finish this question? How about you show your code on a jsFiddle? It's not easy to guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Jonatas Walker  Thanks Jonatas, I have a question about icon property, could your explain the[ anchor, anchorOrigin, offset, offsetOrigin, size) to me, Coz the openlayers web didnt give more explanation and it confuse me, when i change anchor or offset, they both can change icon position, can  offset and size both can cut the icon, Whst does Orign mean, thoses properties confuse me for a long time, could explain them to me, thank you in advance.

Comment: This is another question. Let us finish this one first. If this one is solved, mark as correct.

Comment: Yes, it is done, thanks for your continuous help, I am gonna create another questions to the new question I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a good choice. There are several ways to do this. You can store a property in the feature and check for it, like:

```js
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(ft, layer) { return ft; }
  );
  // here I'm using feature.get('type') but can be any name
  if (feature && feature.get('type') == 'some_value') {
    // now you have the clicked feature
  }
});
```

Note that all features ([`ol.Feature`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html)) has a geometry.

Comment: Thanks for your help, based on your code, i need to add custom property which is called "type", when i define the specific feature. I dont know what i thought is correct or not? Thanks inadvace.

Comment: Doesn't have to be `'type'`. It can be anything.

Comment: As a extension to this question, the layer is requested from some governmental map server, if use this way, i have to make sure if features from them have this kind of property.(they have a property called "name", every image feature has different name， it is hardly to use it） I dont know if there is a general way   to solve this problems by openlayers' build in method.

Comment: ， i try with this statement:  feature.getStyle.getImage() != null, while is has error, when i click the geometry, which show :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getImage' of null.